# Windows Workflow 4 - Running Parallel Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

In our current Windows Workflow model, we intend to have 3 long running processes running at the same time. Each process is responsible for a long running operation (such as copying a file from Location A to Location B).

From my knowledge, WF4 only "supports 1 thread". Is it possible to have 3 activities (each performing a long running operation such as copying files) running at the same time? Or does this mean Workflow is not the right solution for me?

Comment: Related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/23/windows-workflow-foundation-wf4-activities-and-threads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The WF4 threading model is that there is exactly one thread at a time active in a workflow instance so if you have 2 workflows running then the activities from each workflow run in different threads.  The activities within a single workflow are not necessarily using the same thread as each other but each activity is sequential.

The blog mentioned in Maartens post is the place to start.